# Postfix. Restrictions. Send mail from/to specified table

Tags: email, smtp, ldap, postfix-mta, smtp-auth

I have ldap table with logins

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.server-b 'ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=org' '(&(cn=mailFullAccess)(memberUid=username))'
```

output

```
dn: cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=org
gidNumber: 5555
memberUid: fred
memberUid: bob
memberUid: username
cn: mailFullAccess
```

Create a LDAP table

```
search_base = ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=org
server_host = ldap.server
query_filter = (&(cn=mailFullAccess)(memberUid=%u))
result_attribute = memberUid
result_format = %u      internal_hosts_class
scope = sub
bind = yes
```

try check with command

```
postmap -q username ldap:./mailFullAccess_check.cf
```

yields result

```
fred    internal_hosts_class, bob internal_hosts_class, username internal_hosts_class
```

1 match found.

and local domain file list (local_urls.db)

```
mydomain1.ru      OK
mydomain2.ru       OK
mydomain3.ru    OK
```

I want, 'username' can send email only to local domains

i write in main.cf. SMTP auth (saslauthd from LDAP) is working fine.

```
...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        reject
...
smtpd_restriction_classes = internal_hosts_class
internal_hosts_class =   check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/border/local_urls, reject
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access  ldap:/etc/postfix/border/mailFullAccess_check.cf
...
```

postfix restart, send email and get error

```
Feb  3 11:30:53 email postfix/smtpd[10546]: warning: unknown smtpd restriction: "fred"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postmap command

```
postmap -q username ldap:./mailFullAccess_check.cf
```

should **just** return `internal_hosts_class` string. That's why postfix complain with the error *unknown smtpd restriction*.

The solution was modify `mailFullAccess_check.cf` especially in *result_format* become

```
result_format = internal_hosts_class
```